# Unity: Player Stamina and speed manipulation. c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've added stamina to my player where, when the stamina bar is empty, the player speed's reduces to 2. When he collect's a certain powerup it gives him stamina.

When stamina is empty I set `speed = 2`; and when I collect the powerup I fill the stamina bar a little bit and return the speed (`speed = 7;`).

The issue is in the other level. In lvl 2 the map is different and the player will change. If I use the same speed in map 1 and map 2 then the player will be very fast in map2. To account for this, speed is public and I edit it in the inspector.

Right now I am hard coding my speed to `speed = 7`; and this applies to all scenes and levels. How can I make the speed more public and can I edit it only for this scene, or is there a way to say `speed = otherSpeed`?

```
public void AddStamina(int a_staminaToAdd)
{
    // Add stamina when we take coffee.
    g_currStamina += a_staminaToAdd;
    // Disable the "need stamina: text
    g_lowStaminaTxt.enabled = false;

}

public void DeductStamina(int amount)
{
    // only deduct stamina will player is moving on ground
    if (isPlayerGrounded)
    {
        // How much stamina are we going to deduct when player is running?
        g_currStamina -= amount;
        // Change the slider value depending on the stamina
        g_StaminaSlider.value = g_currStamina;

        if (g_currStamina <= 0 )
        {
            //TODO : Go slower
            m_speed = 2;
            g_currStamina = 0;
            g_lowStaminaTxt.enabled = true;
            IsStaminaEmpty = true;

        }

        else
            g_lowStaminaTxt.enabled = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull your variables out of the function scope. And add them to the class level.

```
class foo : monobehaviour
{
    // Give a default value. This can be changed in the editor
    public int SlowSpeed = 2;
    public int FastSpeed = 7;

    // Your functions somewhere here.
}
```

Now that the variables are defined on a class level and are `public` you can change the values using the editor in unity. By default the 2 and 7 will be used, and if you change any of these values in particular scenes, the values will be applied as you changed them.

Now you would need to change your `m_speed = 2;` to `m_speed = SlowSpeed;` for it to work

Comment: Hi, Thank you i will try that and come back to you !

Comment: I agree with @MX D - I would also add that if you find yourself with a large number of stats to update based on the level then it might be worth loading them from a serialised file when the level loads. This is quite simple and can be called from the OnAwake function before play begins.

Comment: should the class "foo" be attached to a gameobject?

Comment: Ty @MX D it works perfectly! i just need the logic and u gave it to me ^^

Comment: Not sure how this persists between levels as per original post?

Comment: @GiuseppeDeFrancesco As understood from the original question. He probably uses different instances of the script in each scene. New instance, uses default values, manually overwrite the script value in the scenes you want to modify it etc etc. Not a very clean way, but a functional way, which seems to have suited the OP.

Comment: @MXD Maybe you're right, but it makes no sense to me. If I end Lvl1 wit Stamina = 5 then in Lvl2 I should still have 5, and that was my understanding of the original question. The OP then deleted most of the text for some reason, don't know what's up here.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to use static members.

A good solution is to store the player's data values in a separate class (so it's multiplayer-friendly as well) like MyStatistics, implementing static properties like this:

```
public class MyStatistics
{
    public static float Stamina { get; set; }
    public static float Health { get; set; }
    public static float Speed { get; set; }
}
```

but not inheriting from MonoBehaviour, so you don't need to attach it to a game object, you just use it anywhere in code by simply using their full qualified name like this

```
        //TODO : Go slower
        MyStatistics.Speed = 2f;
        MyStatistics.Stamina = 0f;
```

One thing to always remember is to reset to the default values those data before to start a new game in case the player dies, otherwise they start a new game with those data still from the previous one because statics stay always there as long as the executable is running.

Comment: That also works, but i can't do it right now because i have already done many stuff and i can't change everything. I need a simpler and faster fix

Comment: Your original post was about persisting between levels where you spawn the player anew. This is the only solution, the other one cannot persist between levels.